# All code paths does not return the value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Any idea what is the issue here i am getting error "Not all code paths return the value " ?

Also is there better way to write code using ES6 instead of using forEach?

main.ts

```
if (rxInfos.length && rxInfos !== undefined) {
    rxInfos.forEach((rxInfo: any) =>  {
        // const requestArray: IRequestURL[] = [];
        for (const member of specialtyMembers) {
            if (member.indexID === rxInfo.indexID) {
                proxyMember = member;
                if (!member.dateOfBirth) {
                    statusDesc = "member dateOfbirth not found";
                    return Promise.reject(this.errorHandler(request, statusDesc));
                }
                const body: any = this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, rxInfo);
                const requestObject = this.specialtyQuestionRequest(body);
                this.requestArray.push(requestObject);
                break;
            }
        }


    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only returning a value (a Promise) if one of your member entries matches.  Not sure what you want to happen if no match, but you probably want to return a promise either way, so add return Promise.resolve() after the loop to handle that case:

```
if (rxInfos.length && rxInfos !== undefined) {
    rxInfos.forEach((rxInfo: any) =>  {
        // const requestArray: IRequestURL[] = [];
        for (const member of specialtyMembers) {
            if (member.indexID === rxInfo.indexID) {
                proxyMember = member;
                if (!member.dateOfBirth) {
                    statusDesc = "member dateOfbirth not found";
                    return Promise.reject(this.errorHandler(request, statusDesc));
                }
                const body: any = this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, rxInfo);
                const requestObject = this.specialtyQuestionRequest(body);
                this.requestArray.push(requestObject);
                break;
            }
        }
        return Promise.resolve();        
    });
}
```

Given what you've provided, there's nothing particularly wrong with using forEach here.

Comment: ok in that case if not member does not match i would send an error using Promise.reject(e) i think i got it

Comment: In that case you'd be reject no matter what, but I think you get the idea.